# Cant find pattern with Scanner in Java 8

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java.util.scanner

I'm working with Java 8 on eclipse and trying to use regex to detect strings in a file, but I'm not detecting anything. I've tested the regex on its own and it successfully match's strings in the file I'm searching. I'm successfully reading from the file because I'm able to print the entire thing. I've also tried simpler regex with the Pattern.compile(), like trying to match a single letter. But no matter the input it never detects anything.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

```
        File logText = new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\textFileLocation.txt");
        Scanner s;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(logText);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+Exception:[^\\n]+");
            System.out.println(s.hasNext(p));
            
            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
            }
            
            s.close();
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here's whats in the file:

*2021-01-14 12:06:33,165 ERROR Server INTERNAL SERVER EXCEPTION #11:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to access bean of type "Address"*

And here's the output

```
false
2021-01-14 12:06:33,165 ERROR Server INTERNAL SERVER EXCEPTION #11:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to access bean of type "Address"
```

Comment: `hasNext(Pattern)`: "_Returns true if the **next complete token** matches the specified pattern_". If your text doesn't *start* with something matching `\w+Exception` (which it does not), then `s.hasNext(p)` will be false at the point when you check it.

Comment: There is no need to double the backslashes in a Windows filename.  `new File("C:\\Users\\textFileLocation.txt")` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the regex API correctly. You can use [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) to check the match. Given below is the demo code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File logText = new File("textFileLocation.txt");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+Exception:[^\\n]+");
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(logText)) {
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String str = s.nextLine();
                boolean found = p.matcher(str).find();
                System.out.println(found);
                if (found) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
2021-01-14 12:06:33,165 ERROR Server INTERNAL SERVER EXCEPTION #11: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to access bean of type "Address"
```

Learn more about Java regex API from **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)**.

Also, I recommend you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close the resource automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Scanner uses any whitespace as a delimiter. I think what you're aiming to do is process the file line by line so I would expect something like the following to work:

```
s = new Scanner(logText).useDelimiter("\\n");
```

More info on the Scanner class can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

- `^` start of line
- `$` end of line
- `.` matches any char except newline.

```
File logText = new File("f:/textFileLocation.txt");
Scanner s;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.+Exception:.*$");
try {
    s = new Scanner(logText);
    String line;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        if (p.matcher(line = s.nextLine()).matches()) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    s.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is close, but I'm wanting to cut off the java.lang. because it would just get redundant. Your endline though is much cleaner that what I had. Thanks! I'm gona steal that

Comment: Whatever you can use is fine.  That's why I participate on this site.  But remember that you could have similarly named exceptions in different packages.  In those cases, the package name can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with a scanner using a Pattern, but you could try compiling your pattern with the Pattern.MULTILINE mode so the ^ and $ will mark the beginning and end of a line *and* the entire input sequence rather than just the entire input sequence.

eg: `Pattern.compile("your pattern", Pattern.MULTILINE);`